# How to get "Windows Phone Pivot Page" when add new item in solution explorer

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am following this example to create Pivot Page for Windows phone application.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff941103(v=vs.105).aspx

In this step,

> Right-click the project in Solution Explorer, click Add, click Add, and click New Item. Select Windows Phone Pivot Page ....

I am using Visual Studio 2013. But I don't see "Windows Phone Pivot Page". Can you please tell me how if I need to install anything for creating Pivot Page?

Comment: Don't you have the universal apps ? It can be there. something like this: http://tctechcrunch2011.files.wordpress.com/2014/04/universal_app_visual_studio.jpg?w=915&h=629

Comment: Yes, I have the universal apps. But that tutorial says 'Windows Phone Pivot Page'. And that tutorial is written pretty recently: 2014.

Comment: yes, but you did the update to 8.1 and the windows phone was merged with the universal app! the ones that say silverlight are for windows phone 8 and the other for 8.1. Check there if you don't have pivot page!

Comment: Sorry , I don't understand where to check. I go to solution explorer and add 'Add'->'New Item'. I search thru all the items under 'Visual C#", there is still no pivot page per the tutorial.

Comment: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplates\CSharp <-- check here if you have this: Windows Phone, Windows Phone 8.1 and Windows Store folders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's WP8.1 Project just Add -> New Item -> Blank Page then add in the basic template for a pivot inside the Grid

Regular WP8.1

---

```XAML
<Pivot>
    <PivotItem Header="one">
        <TextBlock Text="Page one content"></TextBlock>
    </PivotItem>            
    <PivotItem Header="two">
        <TextBlock Text="Page two content"></TextBlock>
    </PivotItem>
</Pivot>
```

---

If it is a WP8.0 8.1 Silverlight App then you can use Add -> New Item -> Windows Phone Pivot Page

[image]

Which really just creates a Blank Page with the above code....